# Generating customized files using bake command in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, customization, cakephp-bake

I am new to cakephp and so impressed with its rapid development. I am eager to know that i have made my own html for (index.ctp,edit.ctp,add.ctp and delete.ctp) and i want 'bake' command to use that html when we run that command in command prompt for generating all files. By doing so it saves time for customized look and when we run every time "bake" command it generates files in our desired format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the answer in CakePHP’s official documentation online, specifically: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html#modify-default-html-produced-by-baked-templates

Answer (score 0):

Read Below article Links related to CAKEPHP: BAKING

1)http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/cakephp-bake-console-in-windows

2)http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

3)http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/baking_with_cakephp

4)http://www.nurelm.com/themanual/2012/01/30/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/

5)http://blog.coldtobi.de/1_coldtobis_blog/archive/301_cakephp_baking_a_application_in_minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create cake bake then use this steps

Open CMD

```
cd /var/www/project/app/Console
```

Then

Run this command

```
php cake.php bake
```

It will show you the all the options